# Tomcat 7: LoggerContext cannot be cast to LoggerContext

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

In a Spring NON Boot application, I want to expose a functionality like the loggers endpoint of the Spring Actuator.
The thing is that for reason I cannot change, we have in the Tomcat `lib` folder a jar that contains, among other things, the logback library.

My code is this (inside a controller):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logging", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@Produces("application/json")
public Map<String, String> getLevel(@RequestParam(required = false) String name) {
    Map<String, String> toReturn = new HashMap<>();
    ILoggerFactory iLoggerFactory = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) iLoggerFactory;
    loggerContext.getLoggerList().forEach(l -> toReturn.put(l.getName(), l.getLevel().levelStr));
    return toReturn;
}
```

here, in the line `LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) iLoggerFactory;` I get the exception:

`ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext`

Which is quite obviously a problem of `ClassLoader`, also taking in consideration that if i put a breakpoint and evaluate the cast, it works properly.
Reading the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), I am thinking that the cast works with the evaluation because in that case it uses my web app class loader, and it does not work at runtime, because tomcat uses the common `ClassLoader` for reading the LoggerContext in startup time, and then it uses my web app `ClassLoader` in the method `LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()`.
So my question is: **how can I force tomcat to use the common classloader in the execution of `LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()`?**

Or, maybe better, **what should be the correct approach?**

Comment: No forcing should need to be done. If the logback lib is going to be provided by adding it to Tomcat, don't package a duplicate along with your application.

Comment: so, is there any way to understand form what jar a class has been loaded?

Comment: Its been a while but I do believe Tomcat defines a directory which will only be exposed to the server classpath and not the application classpaths. Would it be possible to put your jars there? If not... well Java 9 modules are basically invented for situations such as these.